# Default props values in Storybook are not correct

Tags: reactjs, storybook

If I want to use default values for a component's property in React Storybook, it doesn't work. However, there are no issues in a React project.

For example, if I have a `Button` component:

```
import React from "react";

const objs = { a: "a", b: "b" };

export const Button = ({ testProp = Object.keys(objs), text }) => {
  console.log({ objs });
  return <button>{text}</button>;
};
```

`testProp` value is an array and this is [correct](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-benz-35hn6?file=/src/Button.js).

This doesn't work in Storybook, where `testProp` value is `string`

[image]

I am not sure if I need to change some configuration or this is an issue in Storybook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this is storybook [bug](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12455).